# Spark: sum preceding rows

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark to create a DataFrame. I have a column like this one:

```
+---+
|cid|
+---+
|  0|
|  0|
|  0|
|  1|
|  0|
|  1|
|  0|
+---+
```

And would like to use it to create a new column where each row has the sum value of all the preceding rows and it's own value, so it'd end up looking like:

```
+---+
|sid|
+---+
|  0|
|  0|
|  0|
|  1|
|  1|
|  2|
|  2|
+---+
```

Comment: you can look into the window function `sum`.

Comment: sum worked, I wasnt aware it did what I wanted automatically, thanks!